# How i can save checkboxes status in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

So, i have table skips

id: int

student_id: int

status: bool

I am displaying the list of students in checkboxes and I want to save to the table if checked-1 and if not checked-0. Is it possible without JS and JQuery?

Part of controller

```
 if ($request->has('submit')) {
            $skip=new Skip;
            $skip->student_id=$request->student;
            $skip->status=
                $skip->save();
        }
```

Part of view:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    @csrf
@foreach($students as $student)
   <p><input type="checkbox" name="student" value="{{$student->id}}">{{$student->user->name}}</p><br>
    @endforeach
    <button name='submit' type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        Add
    </button>

</form>
```

Comment: If checkbox is not selected, then It wont pass with Request, so you can use a if else statement to check the variable exist or not `$skip->student_id = if($request->has('student')) { 1 } else { 0 };`

Comment: thnx, but what i need to do with $skip->status?

Comment: I dont know what is `$skip->status`, you didn't tell it on your question

Comment: it is status of skip (bool). if the checkbox is checked, it will be 1, if it unchecked-0. And student_id it is id fo student.

Comment: Understand, then that line will be `$skip->status = if($request->has('student')) { 1 } else { 0 };` hope this  helps?

Comment: I did it like this.
 if ($request->has('submit')) {
                $skip=new Skip;
                $skip->student_id=$request->student;
                               if($request->has('student')){
                $skip->status=1;
                              }
                else{
                    $skip->status=0;
                }
                $skip->save();
            }
But only one record is added to the table and the values ​​of unselected checkboxes are not added.

Answer (score 0):

Save as a json value as below

```
 if ($request->has('submit')) {
     $skip=new Skip;
     $skip->student_id=json_encode($request->student);
     $skip->status=
     $skip->save();
 }
```

and update your edit form just decode the field and verify using in_array to enable the checkbox like below.

```
@if(!empty($skip->student_id) && in_array($student->id, json_decode($skip->student_id))){{checked}}@endif
```

Comment: Thnx foк answer, Why are changes being made to $ skip-> student_id and not status? What should be brought there?

Comment: I just copied from your command, am not sure what you wan to save in status.

Comment: i just want to save here 0 if checkbox is unchecked and 1 if checkbox is checked

Comment: then basically its an option not checkbox right? bcz checkbox mean multiple value. For that you can use $request->has('student') ? 1 : 0;

Comment: no, these are checkboxes. That is, I send an array with students to the blade, display it there in checkboxes and I need to send data to the Skip table about who was checked and who was not